# Extracting SubString without knowing Index

Tags: string, string-parsing

I have a string which is something like this
`<term id="123" date="2011-19-08">hello</term>`

now i want to extract the date(format,separator may be different) from the above string and store it in another string.

How could i do that?

Thanks

Comment: even the string can change
<term  date="2011-19-08" id="123">hello..like this also..position is not fixed

Comment: What code language are you using? It is not HTML / JavaScript related, isn't it?

Comment: i'm using java...and that string is fetching a type of xml tag

Comment: you could use indexOf to and look for date=" to find the start of the date and use lastIndexOf and look for "> to find the end of the date and then use substring to extract the characters inbetween?

Examples [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/SearchString.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions (regex) to do it:

If the date format is `0000-00-00`, you could use `([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})`

If you're just trying to extract whatever's in the `date` attribute, you could try: `date="(.+?)"`

Comment: how to use this date="(.+?)" ?
can u please give me an example